# Does it matter where a shift stands in a reset block?

Tags: scala, continuations, delimited-continuations

Suppose, there is a `reset` block with a single `shift`:

```
val r = reset { 
   // do smth. 1
   shift {...}
   // do smth. 2
   // do smth. 3
}
```

Is it correct that I place the `shift` after "do smth. 2" or "do smth. 3" without changing the result `r`? Is it correct that it does not matter where `shift` stands in a `reset` block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It highly depends on what you are making within `shift`. If you just calling provided function like this: `shift((k: Unit => Unit) => k(Unit))` then, in your particular example, it really doesn't matter where `shift` stands.

`Shift` function just captures code that comes after it in other function (in my example this function is called `k`). In other words, this code:

```
val r = reset { 
   // do smth. 1
   shift((k: Unit => Unit) => k(Unit))
   // do smth. 2
   // do smth. 3
}
```

would be rewritten by compiler in something like this (this code just demonstrates general idea and it's not supposed to show what compiler plugin will actually generate):

```
val k = (Unit => Unit) => {
    // do smth. 2
    // do smth. 3
} 

val r = { 
   // do smth. 1
   k(Unit)
}
```

But if you have some logic inside `shift`, like conditional `k` execution, then it really matters where this `shift` stands.

Hope this helps (and I hope, that I understood your question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the answer already given, the place where you CAN move around `shift` is whether to have code before the shift or have it inside the function you pass to `shift`:

```
reset { 
  foo(); bar();
  shift { k => stuff }
  baz()
}
```

is the same as

```
reset {
  foo();
  shift { k => bar(); stuff }
  baz()
}
```